# Unmarshall SOAP Message using JAXB

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

when i unrmarshall below SOAP message, i am getting exception. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:hios="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HIOSCommonObjects">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:ValidIssuersProducts>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:li>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <hios:IssuerProductRequest>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <hios:Issuer>33104</hios:Issuer>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <hios:Product>33104VA001</hios:Product>
            </hios:IssuerProductRequest>
         </tem:li>
      </tem:ValidIssuersProducts>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Unmarshalling code is as below, clazz is "fully qualified name of ValidIssuersProducts" request.

```
public static <T> Object unmarshall(String xml, String clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException, JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Class.forName(clazz));
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream (xml.getBytes());     
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();   
        //JAXBElement<ValidIssuersProducts> obj = (JAXBElement<ValidIssuersProducts>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(input), ValidIssuersProducts.class);

        ValidIssuersProducts value = (ValidIssuersProducts)unmarshaller.unmarshal(input);
        return  value;

    }
```

I am getting below exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{http://tempuri.org/}ArrayOfIssuerProductRequest>,<{http://tempuri.org/}ArrayOfIssuerProductResponse>,<{http://tempuri.org/}IssuerProductRequest>,<{http://tempuri.org/}IssuerProductResponse>,<{http://tempuri.org/}ValidIssuersProducts>,<{http://tempuri.org/}ValidIssuersProductsResponse>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1049)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:148)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:239)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:122)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to unmarshal from the nested element `ValidIssuersProducts` which corresponds to your mapped content instead of the SOAP `Envelope` element.  You can use a StAX `XMLStreamReader` to parse the XML and advance to the correct element and then unmarshal from the `XMLStreamReader at that point.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html